# How can I avoid duplicate records in an Access table when entering data from a subform?

Tags: microsoft-access, forms

I have a MS Access database with three tables:

`Foods (Id, Food_Name, Food_Desc)` 
`Ingredients (Id, Ingredient_Name)`
`IngredientsFoods_mm (Id, Id_FoodsFK, Id_IngredientsFK)`

...in a many-to-many relationship, where `IngredientsFoods_mm` is the table that links the other two.

Now, I made a form with a subform to assign ingredients to foods. In the main form there are the `Food_Name` and `Food_Desc` fields and in the subform there is the `Ingredient_Name` field (a combo box). Seems to work well, but the problem is that when I enter an ingredient that is already in the `Ingredients` table, instead of assign the appropriate record, it creates a duplicate record.

I tried to avoid this by setting an index without duplicates in the `Ingredient_Name` field, but then Access tells me that that would create an integrity error.

The question is, how can I avoid the creation of duplicate records in the `Ingredients` table when entering info from the subform?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are trying to insert into `Ingredients` table when you are supposed to Insert the relationship between `Foods.Id` and `Ingredients.Id` through  the `IngredientsFoods_mm` table.

Make sure your relationships are well defined and that the `IngredientsFoods_mm`'s Primary Key is formed from both `Id_FoodsFK` and `Id_IngredientsFK`.

In here is the explanation of relationships in access. It covers up how to make up a correct many-to-many Relationship model.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304466

Comment: I do think that the relationship are well defined and the PK in the `Id_IngredientsFK` is already formed by the `Id_FoodsFK` and `Id_IngredientsFK` (I've already read the link you provided and yep, the DB have that same structure). The thing is that there are already some records in the `Ingredients` table, but I wanna assign them to or create new records and link them to the `Foods` table.

Answer (score -1):

I have a table for properties that are rented and the properties and stuff but I want to normalise the data. I put all the data that should go in each table together so I know what table to create but I don't know how I'm supposed to only put in one data for a person who has rented 2 properties on different occasions? Do I put in one data and not the other?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).